# Working out the average age of different sub-groups

Tags: statistics, means, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a program to find (an estimated) average age of users. Using data from groups. The problem is how to perform the maths, not the creation of a program to perform the maths. Here's what I know

I don't know the user's exact ages, just how many of them are in the group as a percentage of other groups.

My data:

```
[13-17] => 8.6%
[18-24] => 34.9%
[25-34] => 34.3%
[35-44] => 14.2%
[45-54] => 4.4%
```

I imagine we would base it off a mean such as:

```
[13-17] = 15
```

and transform the percentage of users to out of 1000

```
[13-17] = 86 users @ 15 years old
```

But then I don't know where to go from here to convert this data into an average. Any help and guidance to how this is performed rather than the answer is really appreciated

The data I have is:

```
86 users @ 15 years old
349 users @ 21 years old
343 users @ 30 years old
142 users @ 40 years old
44 users @ 50 years old
```

From this data how would I work out the average age for all the users?

Comment: Does "rather than the answer" mean you only want hints?

Comment: @Lovsovs - No, but I want the method to work out the answer for the problem. Since I'm creating a program using this the data will be different every time so I can't rely on one answer.

Comment: I see.. the reasoning behind the answer is always included in (good) answers here, so you don't need to specify this. Btw, your question is not very clear as it is now; it would be helpful if you'd specify exactly what information you have and what quantity you want to find, and *then* provide an example.

Comment: @lovsovs, I've edited the data to make it easier to read and more about what I'm trying to get out of the question

Comment: Only looking at your question from "The data I have is: ..." and out, do you mean you'd like to find the overall average age of all users? You write you know how many people are what age, so what prevents you from calculating the average? Do you know the definition of the mean/average?

Comment: @Lovsovs From this scenario, I don't know how I would make it work so it balances depending on how many different users are in the different age groups. I could easily come up with an average such as [2,4,6,8,10] and add them up and divide it by the length but that can't be the resolution to this issue

Comment: @Lovsovs - If I'm missing something and you can tell me a simple equation to solve this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to find the average age of *all* users, using only your data in your last box.

1. Convert the number of users in each age group to a percentage. You seem to be able to do this, so I won't show how it is done.
2. Now "weigh" each age with the percentage, as such:

$$0.086\cdot15+0.349\cdot21+0.343\cdot30+0.142\cdot40+0.044\cdot50=26.789$$

This calculation is called the arithmetic mean (or just mean), and tells you the average (in the sense of the mean) age of your users.

Comment: I was just writing the comment about doing it myself. I was looking at the question completely wrong. I wasn't treating it as individual data, instead I was looking at the question  as using a formula rather than simply 86*15+... etc

Comment: @ConorReidd Glad it worked out :)